# Is it possible to use clipToPadding in a ViewGroup for only the top padding?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-paging

So basically I have a chat recycler view. And there are some bottom chips that show on top of the chat at times, now what I want is to fade the chats from the top but show the chat items on the bottom (even behind the chips). Essentially what I want is to apply cliptopadding to the top as true to use fadeEdge in recycler view and use cliptopadding false for the bottom padding? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can give a padding(left, right, top , bottom) like this

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

```
        android:id="@+id/rec"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```